# Error 'can't connect to local host' when I try add project in Boinc client (Google Cloud or AWS)

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, boinc

I'm trying to run project on Google Cloud or AWS.
Every time I see same response 'can't connect to local host'.

I execute commands according to [recommendations](http://www.gridresearchcorp.com/gridcoin/?tutorial):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boinc
boinccmd --lookup_account https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/ email password
```

Why can't the Boinc client connect to local host?

Answer (score 0):

[ChristianBeer](https://github.com/ChristianBeer) has described the issue like following

> The Client and Manager are communicating via TCP so there is always a
>   possibility that a firewall is restricting access to the port the
>   Client uses even on the loopback interface. It is most likely related
>   to a local change of the firewall or dns resolver update.

[Biodoc](https://forums.anandtech.com/members/biodoc.185776/) has given 2 solutions for this issue:

### First Solution:

- 1) open a terminal window
- 2) cd to your BOINC directory (I run the installation script in my
  home directory so my BOINC folder is /home/mark/BOINC)
- 3) start boinc: ./boinc (this will run boinc w/o the GUI interface)
- 4) open another terminal window and cd to BOINC directory
- 5) start boincmgr: ./boincmgr (this will start the GUI interface)

It's kind of cumbersome but it works for me.

### Second Solution:

Here's another option (longterm solution).

Say you want to manage your boinc projects on your linux box from another machine on your local network.

On the linux box:

- 1) stop boinc and open a terminal window.
- 2) cd to BOINC directory
- 3) gedit ./gui_rpc_auth.cfg (this file contains the password for
  remote "control" of boinc)
- 4) the default password is insanely long so delete it and change it
  to something easy to remember.
- 5) save the file and close gedit
- 6) find out the ip address of this machine by typing/running ifconfig
- 7) write down the ip address and consider changing you router
  settings to fixed ip addresses. Otherwise, the next time your reboot
  the machine it may grab a different ip address.
- 8) start boinc with this command: ./boinc --allow_remote_gui_rpc
- 9) go to another computer and start the boinc gui
- 10) go to the "advanced" menu and choose "select computer.."
- 11) type in ip address and password for your linux box and now you
  should the boinc tasks/projects on the remote linux box.
- 12) Important (took me a while to figure this out): to go back to
  your local machine, go the advanced menu and "select computer", then
  type in localhost and the local password should pop-up automatically.

### Resource Link:

1. [linux boinc can't connect to localhost](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/linux-boinc-cant-connect-to-localhost.2133499/)
2. [Boinc manager can't connect to client using "localhost"](https://github.com/BOINC/boinc/issues/1306)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for answers.

During long investigation, I also have been found more easy way to start Boinc on AWS/Google Cloud

- sudo apt-get install boinc-client boinc-manager
- sudo /etc/init.d/boinc-client start
- boinccmd --project_attach www.worldcommunitygrid.org Weak Account Key
- sudo /etc/init.d/boinc-client restart

Then possible to check status:
- sudo /etc/init.d/boinc-client status
- boinccmd --get_simple_gui_info

This commands can be helpful for other contributors.